# Why is my Flask app only accessible from other computers?

Tags: python, flask, networking

I have a default "Hello World" flask app running on my Windows 10 machine. Here is the code I'm using:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, World!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

When I access it from another computer on my network (My phone in this case) I get `Hello, World!` in the browser, and the flask app outputs `<my phone ip> - - [25/Feb/2020 15:55:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -` to the console.

The weird part is that when I try to access `localhost:5000` on the computer running the app, the browser hangs, and the flask app outputs `127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2020 15:57:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -` to the console. It will hang forever.

Do you think this is a problem with my network configuration? I've had weird things happen in the past as a result of having Wireshark installed, Hyper-V, etc.? I've already disabled all virtual adapters other than my wifi.

**Edit 1:**
If I open another python interpreter I can use `requests` and it gives me `b'Hello, World!'` as the response content. Both browsers I've tried, Chrome and MS Edge, hang.

**Edit 2:**
For now I'm just going to resort to using Postman, since I'm using this to design an API anyway. I'm just confused why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

Is windows firewall on? The code looks fine. This a network issue. Turn your firewall off to test.